# Easiest way to write overloads

Tags: c#, overloading

Whats the easiest way to write overloads for methods where I dont really care in what order the user inputs the paramaters and where the type is always differently?

For example:

```
public void DoSomething(String str, int i, bool b, DateTime d)
{
    //do something...
}
```

Now I would like to have the possibility that you can call the method in any possible way, for example:

```
DoSomething(1, DateTime.Now, "HelloWorld", false);
DoSomething(DateTime.Now, 1, "HelloWorld", false);
DoSomething("HelloWorld", DateTime.Now, 1, false);
DoSomething(false, DateTime.Now, "HelloWorld", 1);
//and so on...
```

Is there really no other way, than to duplicate the method over and over again and rearrange the parameters?

I specially think its annoying when you specify default values for parameters and either need to specify the name when calling the method, or set the defaults.

Comment: You might not care what order the user inputs the parameters but surely you don't need to cater for them doing it however they want? I'd probably suggest creating a small parameter object though to take all the parameters and then you can populate that in any order and pass that on. Though mainly I would suggest letting the people using your code just having to deal with having to put the parameters in whatever order you tell them to.

Comment: Why would you want something like that? You have the same amout of parameters, but you want them in a different order

Comment: There are many reasons you can't do this. What if two types can be implicitly converted between eachother? How will the compiler know which one you meant? You can use parameter names and reorder them even without default values, but even then it's because the compiler needs the information.

Comment: @Magus: You can do it. The compiler will recognise the signatures as different as long as the parameters are all different types. If it gets confused by what one you are calling (eg because it has parameters long and int and you are are passing an int to both) it will complain that it isn't able to disambiguate. In this case you can just cast one of them to the appropriate type and the compiler knows.

Comment: I know that, but he's asking why the order of parameters matters in the first place, because he'd like it to not. If you have parameters of the same type, it'd be impossible for the compiler. Having a consistent order with well named parameters is a benefit, not a curse.

Comment: If there is a maximum of one parameter of any type then I guess you could declare the method as DoSomething(object par1, object par2...) and check the actual types within the method. Can't see the point though

Comment: You could use `params object[]`. Good luck identifying the order.

Comment: @Magus: My point was that even if types can be implicitly converted it will still work. If the method signatures would be identical then it won't work but he explicitly said that all types were different so in this case he very much *can* do this. Its just not necessarily a good idea. My only objection is to your statement that you can't do it because in this case you can. Otherwise I agree with what you've said.

Comment: @Chris: I think we agree in general. You're definitely right about the implicit conversions, but I'd say that the fact that you'd have to cast is part of the reason the order matters. Considering the prevalence of hierarchies, if the language was built so the order didn't matter, more than half of parameters might need casting to work. That's what I want to convey to the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if your methods grow in parameters count you should seriously begin thinking about creating a specific class that can hold all this data:

```
public class MyData
{
   public string Str {get;set;}

   public int I {get;set;}

   public bool B {get;set;}

   public DateTime D {get;set;}
}
```

and have a single method signature:

```
public void DoSomething(MyData data)
{
    //...
}
```

and you may use it like this:

```
DoSomething(new MyData {I = 1, Str = "Hello", D = DateTime.Today, B = false});
```

This approach has the additional advantage that it provides much more scalability, since you can add any amount of new properties into that class without having to change your method signatures at all.

Other than that, see [Named Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389667/643085).

Comment: While this doesn't directly solve the part he finds annoying, at least it doesn't immediately offer it as the solution, and offers a solution that is generally better in many cases.

Comment: If he finds named parameters annoying then I can't imagine this being any better

Comment: @Dominic I would than have to write mutliple contstructor overloads. :)

Comment: @Magus I would than have to write mutliple contstructor overloads. :)

Comment: @RandRandom in general, you don't "pass" random stuff coming from "nowhere" to a method, you create classes which represent the data you're working with and operate with that throughout the course of your application. I really fail to see why you want to achieve anything like that.

Comment: In my case, I have a method with 6 parameters where 5 of them have a default value. Since 5 of them already have a default value and the method just works fine with just calling 1 parameter I wanted to have a method where you can specify any of the other 5 paramaters. I can understand that you have to specify the name when its the same type, but with a method that has different types as parameters I am not really satisfied with the restriction that you have to specify the name, why cant it compile without it? I just hoped there is a easier way where the compiler checks what method to call.

Comment: @RandRandom: I answered that just now in a comment on the question. It's largely to do with hierarchies, and the fact that the compiler is a program, not a human. It can't understand intent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Named Parameters, take a read int his MSDN Article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg581066.aspx

Comment: Pretty sure the question included him finding that annoying.

Comment: @Magus yeah thats correct, but seeing 3 answers telling me about it - I didnt quite made my point clear. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) and specify the names of the parameters with the arguments in any order:

```
DoSomething(i:1, d:DateTime.Now, str:"HelloWorld", b:false);
DoSomething(d:DateTime.Now, i:1, str:"HelloWorld", b:false);
DoSomething(str:"HelloWorld", d:DateTime.Now, i:1, b:false);
DoSomething(b:false, d:DateTime.Now, str:"HelloWorld", i:1);
```

Or you could also use [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) but then you forgo type checking

Comment: In the question, he says that's annoying. He knows about it.

Comment: params? you mean with a object[] and than check in the method, which param is the certain type?

Comment: @RandRandom yeah, that's one way I could see of doing this

Comment: Even that would only help if you can be sure your parameters are always different types. It's impossible to tell if they aren't. And even doing it with a `params object[]` invites more issues, because the types required and their number is unspecified.

Comment: @Magus it's definitely not a good way to go, was just suggesting an option if he really wanted that behaviour. You could check the types and the length of the array and throw an argument exception if it fails his expectations, but that's still not great